# wait for request and then tableview call

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am using a `ASIHTTPRequest` to get a value from the `url`. this process is done in view did load. and I get value from a `url` store in an array. I have one table view. The problem is when I run the app table view is first called and it take array value is 0. my request is taking some time for loading. how to solve it.i am new to us. help me. i want to lode that array in to my tableview.

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

```
 NSString *s= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:///blog/api/get_category_posts/?id=%@",value];
    s=[s stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:s];
    ASIHTTPRequest *req2=[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:url1];
    [req2 setDelegate:self];
    [req2 startAsynchronous];}-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{


        tableResourceArray=[request.responseString JSONValue];


        NSLog(@"TempArray:%d",tableResourceArray.count);} -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

    return tableResourceArray.count;
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly do you want to achieve??

Comment: load that tablerescurcearray in to my table view. this is my process

Comment: Once you get the response from service into your array, you can just call `[yourTableView reloadData]` and it will call the dataSource methods again.

Comment: where should i call this. i am fresher bro.

Comment: After line `tableResourceArray=[request.responseString JSONValue]` in `requestFinished` method.

Comment: bro i have another doubt can u help me

Comment: If its closely related, u can ask here in comment or by editing your question. But if its different, you can ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just reload table after get response.

in your case

```
[req2 startAsynchronous];}
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{


        tableResourceArray=[request.responseString JSONValue];
        [tableName reloadData];       // ** that's you need**

        NSLog(@"TempArray:%d",tableResourceArray.count);
```

}
     -(NSInteger)tableView:   (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {

```
    return tableResourceArray.count;
}
```

Comment: Calling reloadData in `numberOfRowsInSection` is not useful and is not going to be called.